# django oauth2 Session value state missing error

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

there is my social auth setting and it works correctly in local-host but on server it returns session value state missing error. i have tested similar questions in stack overflow but the answers didn't solved my problem.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = ''

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True


LOGIN_URL = '/auth/login/google-oauth2/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['state']
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

white_list = ['http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile']

DJOSER = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_ALLOWED_REDIRECT_URIS': white_list,
    'ACTIVATION_URL': '#/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_TOKEN_STRATEGY': 'djoser.social.token.jwt.TokenStrategy',
    'SERIALIZERS': {},
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```